# Updating catalog gets failed in Poedit

Tags: poedit

I'm having this issue since 1 day. Till now, I didn't figure out what exactly is the issue. Whenever I create a new catalog, and save it. It throws me the error. Does any have idea about it? Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press on Button "Details" an see, what the error exactly is. Post it here to got some more help.

I got some error like "please set --from-code Parameter". This was not set, so I set it on Katalog-Pereferences to UTF-8. After this, it works like a charm.